# AWS SDK for node.js not picking up credentials when running in ECS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have this code:

```
const uploadAllToS3 = () => {
    console.log("upload useless file to s3, just to test access rights");
    new AWS.S3().putObject({
        Bucket: scheduledJobsConstants.s3BucketName(),
        Key: `test/${new Date()}.txt`, Body: "Hello!",
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(`env:${inspect(process.env)}
        provider:${AWS.CredentialProviderChain.defaultProviders}
        cred:${inspect(AWS.config.credentials)}
        err:${inspect(err)}`.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""));
    });
};
```

When this code runs in ecs(which assumes a role that has access to the S3 bucket), I will get this in the log:

The env part of the log:

```
env: {
    PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
    HOSTNAME: '485bbd95f87d',
    AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI: '/v2/credentials/be3d4d7c-28b6-47e6-8081-cd746d95cb28',
    ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE: '/opt/ecs/metadata/8c0b731d-49ce-4e19-bf79-64087b433876/ecs-container-metadata.json',
    NODE_VERSION: '8.9.4',
    YARN_VERSION: '1.3.2',
    NPM_CONFIG_PROGRESS: 'false',
    HOME: '/root'
  }
```

The "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" is present in env var, so I assume the sdk should be able to pick that up.

The provider part of the log is just 4 functions that's defined in the sdk code, the 4th of which would return "ECSCredentials" if it sees "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" in env var.

Strangely the cred part of the log is "null" in ECS.
When I run this locally(where I manually assume a role), the cred part of the log is "EnvironmentCredentials", and the file gets uploaded to S3.

The err part of the log is:

```
{ Forbidden: null 
at Request.extractError (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:557:35) 
at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20) at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10) 
at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14) 
at Request.transition (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10) 
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12) 
at /app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10 
at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9) 
at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12) 
at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18) 
message: null, 
code: 'Forbidden', 
region: null, 
time: 2018-01-14T06:30:00.490Z, 
requestId: '4E7121D88BA0FEF1', 
extendedRequestId: 'D5uiXf5EI/OLHeaPhYX67C384ba3SF1I950N78hJWw8Vv4XGQ0opSLOQlXaxVFW31g252dx8YUc=', 
cfId: undefined, 
statusCode: 403, 
retryable: false, 
retryDelay: 118.50320949834776 }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or my env var?

Should I print more logs to help diagnose this problem?

Please advise, thanks.

==========Update==========

I have ran this code in ECS

    `` const curlCommand = `curl http://169.254.170.2${process.env.AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI}`;
    exec(curlCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(`${curlCommand} err:${error} out:${stdout} stderr:${stderr}`);
    }); ``

The result I got is:

  `{
    "SecretAccessKey": "long string",
    "Token": "very long string",
    "Expiration": "2018-01-14T08:55:04+0000",
    "AccessKeyId": "shorted string"
  }`

So if the sdk had called http://169.254.170.2${process.env.AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI}, it should have gotten a correct response.

Comment: Are you sure that the provider being used is the same on your local and on the ec2 instances ? For example the ec2 instance might have got an invalid cred from the metadata service

Comment: @Malice AWS.config.credentials is null when running in ECS. my assumption is that this should not be null since "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" is present in env var. is that a correct assumption?

Comment: You might need to initializa AWS.EC2MetadataCredentials  and assign it to aws.config.credentials. As far as I know, it doesnt do this unless it is done explicitly

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2MetadataCredentials.html

Comment: @Malice thank you for the doc link. my code is not running in EC2, it's running in ECS containers. according to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS.html#ECSCredentials-property  it should load ecs credentials if AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI exists, which is the case judging by my log

Comment: @Malice i will try to set ECSCredentials explicitly and see how it goes, thanks

Comment: Ah I'm outdated, But I still dont see why you believe that the credentials was retrieved by the application ?

Comment: @Malice https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/829ad3c7d48512e507be2ab30052ad0d8bdb0c2c/lib/node_loader.js#L37-L51  in the sdk's source code, the default provider chain includes ecs credentials, so I was assuming it'll pick that up automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163129/discussion-between-malice-and-cuipengfei).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to do

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.ECSCredentials(options);
```

presumably because credentials for aws-sdk credentials were not configured/ configured incorrectly.

Comment: Problem solved.

It was somehow related to node version.

My code was running in ECS, with a base docker image: node:8.9.4.

I switched to node:9.4, which is the latest version, that solved the problem.

Don't know why, but it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `AWS.ECSCredentials.get` or `getPromise` to make sure credentials are loaded before you use them:

```js
const ecsCredentials = new AWS.ECSCredentials({ ... });
await ecsCredentials.getPromise();
AWS.config.credentials = ecsCredentials;
```

Check this thread for more info: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3281#issuecomment-637171993.

Answer (score 1):

I am using CloudFormation and in my case, I had to specify `TaskRoleArn` in the `TaskDefinition.Properties` before the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` was injected into my container. Once it was, the AWS SDK automatically picked up my credentials.